# Yii: How to edit a slave CDbConnection using the tennant settings when using multiple DBs

Tags: php, yii

I need to edit the `dbx` connection whenever needed, while the app runs.

I have defined 2 db connection settings;

`db` is for the central db

`dbx` is for any other slave db (my app has a slave db for each user)

for each user, the `dbx` has its own username and password, wich will be saved in a db table;

```
'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'dbx' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, the tested solution is:

```
<?php

class DomainSlaveM extends Domain {

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static $server_id = 1;
    public static $slave_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$slave_db = Yii::app()->dbx;
        if (self::$slave_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            $config = require(Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/config/location/setting.php');
            $connectionString = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=irdb' . self::$server_id;
            self::$slave_db->connectionString = sprintf($connectionString, 'dbx');
            self::$slave_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$slave_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

}
```

and the code is:

```
    DomainSlaveM::$server_id = 1;
    $model_domain_slave_m = DomainSlaveM::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => 1));
    if ($model_domain_slave_m) {
        $model_domain_slave_m->updated = time();
        if ($model_domain_slave_m->validate() && $model_domain_slave_m->save()) {

        }
    }
```

original article found at:[click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#setAttributes-detail)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you may not configuring `dbx` on configs and after user login creates it component with needed params before any using dbx in code. You can do it by (describes [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponent-detail)):

> ```
> Yii::app()->createComponent('dbx', array(
>         'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc2',
>         'username' => <user db login>,
>         'password' => <user db pass>,
>         'charset' => 'utf8',
>         'tablePrefix' => '',
>         'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
>     ))
> ```

For removing existing component you can do `Yii::app()->createComponent('dbx', null)` and then create this component with other's parameters

Comment: actually, i found my answer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#setAttributes-detail the last comm

Comment: Yes, it's pretty solution, but don't forget reconnect by: `Yii::app()->dbx->active=false; Yii::app()->dbx->active=true`